# IntelliJ Idea: Undo remove module by checkout other git branch

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have removed module from my root-reactor module.

The change was in private git branch.

Then I wanted to cancel this change.

I have shelve changes and checkout to master branch - the modulde exist but as simple directory, not as module.

Its pom.xml file marked as ignored with line on its name.

I tried the following - and nothing help:

1. reimport all maven project
2. Generate sources and update folders
3. Invalidate cache and restart intelliJ
4. Clean-install root-reactor
5. Repair IDe

Any idea?

Comment: See the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | **Ignored Files** settings.

Answer (score 0):

go to Settings

Search action: ignored files (at left side)
Then you get a list of your ignored files.
Search after pom.xml of your removed module and un-check it.